# Is this sentence grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions

> Had Nick been here on time, we **would not have missed** the train. [[Introduction]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0230551211)
>   Had Nick been here on time, we **would not miss** the train.

Is the second sentence grammatically wrong, or are the two sentences different just in their nuance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standing on the train platform today, waiting for Nick, you might say, anxiously:

> “If Nick **is** here we **will** not miss the train.”

If you narrate this tomorrow, you will *backshift* the tenses:

> “Yesterday I said that if Nick **was** here we **would** not miss the train.”

Now suppose that in fact Nick is *not* on time. Now your condition, your *IF* clause,  is an *irrealis* or *counterfactual*. Just before the train leaves you might say, despairingly:

> “If Nick **were** here we **would** not miss the train.”

And afterwards, as the train pulls out of the station, leaving you on the platform, you might say bitterly:

> “If Nick **had been** here we **would** not **have** missed the train.”

What is confusing here is that **would** does double duty: it may act as either the past indicative form or the present conditional form of **will**. You have to figure out which is in play from the context.

Answer (score 4):

The second is an ungrammatical way of expressing the first. The first part of the sentence imagines something that didn't happen in the past, whereas *we would not miss the train* envisages some present or future event. An example of its use might be *If you weren't so late getting to the station every day, we wouldn't miss the train so often.*

Comment: So the example’s replacement that is [linked](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/does-would-have-choked-mean-she-had-the-bread) [would have choked -> would choke] could be possible for there’s no explicit imagination; yet in this case, ‘would not miss the train’ should not be used for there’s explicit envisagement of something that didn't happen in the past?

Comment: @Listenever. Well, yes. The whole incident is set in the past.

Comment: @List, no, I don't think. You have to learn the so-called "consecutio temporum" rule, according to which the second case ("would not miss") is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

{Had it been} {that would have} - is the rule.

Hence the first sentence is correct and the second one is not.